# How to get Mobile Device Identification in Webservice

Tags: android, web-services, mdm

I have android native application & web service. Our application is University application. Generate long live token for session issue.So we planned to go for MDM, i searched on Google, , I got some solution

```
Open Mobster (Open Source Mobile Enterprise Backend)
Apache USerGrid_ (Mobile Backend as a service) 
OpenMeap - not support native
```

Problem is I could not find out , whether this MDM are provide device identification facility.If any one knows about it please tell me. Device identification may be any unique id or mac address

or If i am going to developed our own middle layer , how we can get mac address from request header. without passing to service method , from the request should take.

is there any way to take sort-out this issue?

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Here is how OpenMEAP grabs the Mac address and passes it in the header.

```
package com.openmeap.thinclient;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import com.openmeap.http.HttpRequestExecuter;
import com.openmeap.http.HttpResponse;
import com.openmeap.util.Utils;

public class FirstRunCheck implements Runnable {
private SLICConfig config;
private String macAddress;
private HttpRequestExecuter executer;
public FirstRunCheck(SLICConfig config, String macAddress, HttpRequestExecuter executer) {
    this.config = config;
    this.macAddress = macAddress;
    this.executer = executer;
}
public void run() {
    if( config.isDevelopmentMode().equals(Boolean.TRUE) ) {
        return;
    }
    if( config.getNotFirstRun()==null ) {
        config.setNotFirstRun(Boolean.TRUE);
        try {
            String macWithSalt = macAddress+".OPENMEAP#$!@3__234";
            String hashValue = Utils.hashInputStream("sha1", new ByteArrayInputStream(macWithSalt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
            HttpResponse response = executer.get("http://usage.openmeap.com/tracker.gif?hash="+hashValue);
            Utils.consumeInputStream(response.getResponseBody());
        } catch( Exception ioe ) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

}